# Is it possible to parse with JSON file using org.json in Java?

Tags: java, json

How could be parse it for example?

```
{
    "392bc124":        {
            "ts":        {
                    "value":        "File content"
            },
            "type":        "File content",
            "sn":        "File content"
    },
    "07dba83e":        {
            "ts":        {
                    "value":        "File content"
            },
            "type":        "File content",
            "sn":        "File content"
    },
    "a24faa33":        {
            "ts":        {
                    "value":        "File content"
            },
            "type":        "File content",
            "sn":        "File content"
    }
}
```

I know how it to works only for with one

```
{
    "devices" : [
        {
            "name"  : "07dba83e"
            "sn"    : "c8abddf44e49986ff2cd03be6fd2b1fc",
            "type"  : "output",
            "value" : "100"
        },
        {
            "name"  : "392bc124"
            "sn"    : "644f2821b26a7d6c93720b26c5044b40",
            "type"  : "input",
            "value" : "12"
        },
        {
            "name"  : "a24faa33"
            "sn"    : "2893a640fd1b6102c84f035c42ee4257",
            "type"  : "dimmer",
            "value" : "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

how could i get "392bc124" json object if i don't know the name ("392bc124")? On the second sample i have an array and it ok, but i don't know, are there any ways to parse the first one?

Comment: Have you tried it?  What was the result?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you would use [getNames](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getNames%28org.json.JSONObject%29) or [keys](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29)